# Performance issue with encrypted app.config file 

Tags: c#, encryption, c#-4.0, app-config

i am working on an application where we have decided for a number of reasons that the app.config file should be encrypted.  We are using `SectionInformation.ProtectSection` with the `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` to encrypt all of the sections.  This part works fine and the application is able to read the encrypted information.  My question with this approach is about performance.  I have run into an issue load testing our application where using the encrpyted config is almost **2x slower** under load than with an unencrypted config.  So when my application starts up does the config get unencrypted and cached in memory or not?  Or does it actually go to disk everytime?  I have done alot of searching and have not found a difinitive answer to what exactly is going on here. Thanks for your help!

I'd like to add that this application uses the connectionString property a great deal to access the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the answer to my own question.  As it turned out the performance hit i was taking with the encrypted config was related to a bug in our solution's framework code.  Basically, there was left over code from something we were attemting to implement which was opening the config from disk everytime we went to access the connection string or any app setting:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration()
```

I changed this code to just use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]` and everything is working great now.  So what I found out was that `ConfigurationManager` reads from disk the first time you access a property and also decrypts the file that first time only.  After that it's just reading the values from the decrypted sections in memory.

Comment: So actually, my answer was right? "So when my application starts up does the config get unencrypted and cached in memory or not? Or does it actually go to disk everytime?"...just sayin

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick test and it looks like it's loaded into memory.  Below is the code I ran.  After the first WriteLine() I opened the config, manually changed it, and saved the config file. The second WriteLine() printed out the old value and not the new one,so I would conclude that it doesn't open the file back up after it reads it once.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TestSettings"));
    Console.ReadLine();
    //Before hitting return I changed the value of TestSettings manually
    Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TestSettings"));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought that much too.  But why am i taking such a performance hit then using encryption in the config? Could it still be encrypted in memory and everytime i need to access the connection string it has to decrypt the section? This is the information that is difficult for me to find.

Comment: Yeah, it could be.  If you're hitting the same settings over and over again though I would just pull them in to a variable.  I try to limit the number of times I make calls to the config file.

Comment: Actually my next test was going to be to cache the string myself and see if this helps. I guess this is just one of those undocumented things you have to figure out for yourself. Thanks again. I'll update on the results of my test in case anyone else comes across this.  I'd vote you up too but not able to do that just yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx

hard to beat that performance

Comment: Thanks for this, but as i mentioned i am already able to encrypt the sections of my app.config file perfectly fine. I did not notice anywhere in that post however where it mentions anything about performance of the running app with an encrypted config.